# setting minimum level of chart in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, charts

By default, minimum level of ASP.NET chart control is `0`, I want to set this level to `-1`. So that `0` value on y-axis can be shown correctly...

Comment: Is this in WebForms or MVC?  If it's WebForms, you should just be able to set the MinValue for the Y-Axix in an attribute of the control.  If it's MVC, you'll have to set it in code.  Can you post an example of what you have?

Comment: I am using web form ..please seng piece of code to set minimum value of y-axis

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var chart = new Chart();

//
// Code to define chart areas etc...
//

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -1;
```